# how to get the key for the values in the dictionary in python

Tags: python, key

I am trying to filter a file based on some criteria. I have managed to write a python script to filter the lengths. See below

```
genes = {} # empty list

with open(infile, "rU") as fh_in:
    for line in fh_in:
        line = line.strip()
        if line[0] == ">":
            gene_names = line[1:]
            genes[gene_names] = ''
        else:
            genes[gene_names]+=line

for (name,val) in genes.items():
    val = len(val)
    if val < 200:
        print val
```

Now for all values less than 200, how do i get keys? I know how to get values for keys but not the other way around.

Any help!

Comment: Try `print name` or `print name, val`?

Comment: Sorry i didn't realized that it is that easy. Thanks anyway